# ReflectionTestUtils - Setting field of type [null] on target object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am new with Unit testing and Mockito. I'm trying to write tests for my Dao class:

```
@Repository
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    
    @Value("${users.find.by_id}")
    private String findByIdQuery;
    
    private RowMapper<User> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
        user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        user.setEnabled(rs.getBoolean("enabled"));
        return user;
    };

    public UserDaoImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {
        super();
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(int id) {
        SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = template.queryForObject(findByIdQuery, param, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
}
```

In my simple test I simply added @Mock anotation for my *NamedParameterJdbcTemplate*, and trying to put it into the *UserDaoImpl*:

```
public class UserDaoTest {
    
    @Mock
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    @InjectMocks
    public UserDao userDao;
    
    @Test
    public void findByIdTest() {
        template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("classpath:db/schema.sql")
                .addScript("classpath:db/test-data.sql")
                .build());
        userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userDao, "template", template);
        Mockito.when(userDao.findById(1).get().getEmail()).thenReturn("Keanu@gmail.com");
        
        User user = userDao.findById(1).get();
        assertNotNull(user);
        assertEquals("Keanu@gmail.com", user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Each time I run the test, I get **java.lang.NullPointerException** for the field *template*. Cant find what is the correct way of implementing the test.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code:

1. You are using `@Value` directly in a property and you will have a hard time setting up your test for the class with this.
2. You are missing the enablement of Mockito annotations in your test.
3. You are instantiating `UserDaoImpl` in your test method when you should be relying on the instance created by Mockito.
4. You are also creating a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and then using `ReflectionTestUtils` to wire it to the `UserDaoImpl` object.
5. And you are mocking the wrong object. You need to mock the calls to `template`, not `userDao`.

To tackle the first one you need to change `UserDaoImpl` as follows:

```java
@Repository
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    
    private String findByIdQuery;
    
    private RowMapper<User> rowMapper = (rs, rowNum) -> {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
        user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        user.setEnabled(rs.getBoolean("enabled"));
        return user;
    };

    public UserDaoImpl(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template, @Value("${users.find.by_id}") String findByIdQuery) {
        super();
        this.template = template;
        this.findByIdQuery = findByIdQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findById(int id) {
        SqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = template.queryForObject(findByIdQuery, param, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(user);
    }
}
```

To tackle 2., 3., 4. and 5. you need to enable Mockito annotations programmatically and remove `userDao = new UserDaoImpl();` line and also the `template` variable from the method test as follows:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDaoTest {
    @Mock
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;
    
    public UserDao userDao;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        userDao = new UserDaoImpl(template, "query-string");
    }

    @Test
    public void findByIdTest() {
        // Arrange
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
        user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
        user.setEmail(rs.getString("Keanu@gmail.com"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        user.setEnabled(rs.getBoolean("enabled"));
        Mockito.when(template.queryForObject(anyString(), any(SqlParameterSource.class), any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(user);

        template.queryForObject(findByIdQuery, param, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(User.class));

        // Act
        User user = userDao.findById(1).get();

        // Assert
        assertNotNull(user);
        assertEquals("Keanu@gmail.com", user.getEmail());
    }
}
```

Comment: With *@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class* problem remains. The second option threw *failed to release mocks*. Looks like I have version conflict. Attached the pom.xml above.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it ;)

Comment: now it actually works, but I have to change somehow the functionality, because I want to store my queries in a single .properties file.

Comment: If my answer helped you consider upvoting it and even accepting it as the answer so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!

Comment: It's great that it is working but the issue here is that findByIdQuery is a private and therefore it cannot be found by Mockito so use Java Reflection API to make it accessible and there itself set it value.